# Can't Find Color Mapping for Fluid Simulation in 2.9

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I can't find the color mapping option for fluid sim in 2.9 where is it? I go to viewport display in my setting but can't seem to find it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

they removed it from blender. You have to use 2.8